# Exporting webpage as PDF from Safari

Tags: macos, safari, pdf, safari-extensions

I seek a  web clipper some apps (Notion, Bear, etc) have but I want it from Safari on the Mac without adding third party extensions or apps.

I know you can go to `Safari>File>Export as PDF` but

1. it is not fast
2. it is quite bad at formatting text.

Is there any way to export a formatted webpage to PDF with Safari?

Comment: Why not just print the page and save as PDF from the print dialog?

Comment: We strongly prefer one question per question. Feel free to ask a similar version on markdown. this is edited to be a single question on PDF.

Comment: @nohillside The obtained fontsize is quite high. Even moderate-length web articles end up in 6-7 pages in the PDF file.

Comment: Well, that‘s what is possible with built-in functionality. Not sure you have more options with extensions though